# Can't change styles except in theme options > Custom CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a theme, and I created a child one of it. My goal was to be able to change some styles using style.css archive.

Problem is that it's not working. Actually, Changes don't apply even if I change style.css of parent's theme.

They only work if I apply them directly in my Theme Options > Custom CSS. It's a theme with a lot of options, but I don't like to modify CSS through the custom panel, I'd rather do it in style.css child's theme. Does it have something to do with a function? Could I delete such a thing?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you double checked that there's no caching set up with your theme/plugins? Have you ensure that your child theme is activated? Can you confirm if your stylesheet is loading? (ctrl + u to view source code and see if your child stylesheet is even loading in). this will hopefully give you a place to start.

Comment: Thanks Frits for your answer. I've already cleared the cache, and now something has happened. Changes in parent's style.css does affect the child-theme now, but still not in style.css from child-theme. I've checked source code as you said, and turns out the stylsheet is not even loading. I'm using @import url on that file and it should work since my child theme is correctly activated. What can it be?

Comment: Ok, I've read that @import is not longer best practice. I'm trying to fix following documentation of wordpress codex.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve that reading [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)

Thanks!